# Relationship between electric field and distance

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge

I am working on a lab report that asks a conceptual question related to one of the labs we did on electrostatic fields. For the context of my question, here is how the experiment is set up.

We have a conducting paper attached to a cork board. At the center of the conducting paper is a dot which we plug to the negative terminal of the battery. A circle of radius about $8$ $cm$ encircles this dot, and we plug the positive terminal to this.

The lab requires us to test the electric field due to this charge distribution along the horizontal axis at varying distances from the dot at the center. We took data from 1 cm all the way out to $8$ $cm$.

The conceptual question is: How does the electric field vary with distance in this setup? Based on our calculations, we are to use an assumed power law such as $$E(r) = Cr^n$$ to fit this line, and determine what 'n' might be.

Our plot looks very similar to a relationship such as $$E ∝ 1/r^{0.2}$$ or $$E ∝ 1/r^{0.3}$$.
However, theoretically, the field due to a single charge should vary as $1/r^2$. 
My question is - is such a large deviation justified due to this dot-ring setup, and if so, how?

EDIT: it's possible for me to fit it right if I use $E = \frac {C}{r^2}$ and take an arbitrary C value to shape it so that it looks like the plot we had. Not sure if this helps at all.

Comment: They really make you do such an experiment? Sigh... that's physics teaching at its worst. The basic idea is kind of OK, there are potential surfaces in such a conductive material, but they are not to be mistaken for the equipotential surfaces of a static electric charge. The setup is, at best, a model for an electric charge. Having said that, there are a couple of possibilities: you made a large measurement error or the paper you were using was damaged and didn't have sufficiently constant conductivity. It's kind of hard to tell what happened without the hardware and control measurements.

Comment: In an ideal setup, though, how would such a setup vary assuming that the ring and dot had equal charges that cancel each other out (meaning, a Gaussian surface drawn enclosing both of them would have zero flux passing through it.)

What n should there have been for E ∝ 1/r^n ideally?

Comment: You are basically looking at Ohm's law in vectorial form: $\vec j=\sigma\vec E$. Since the current has nowhere to go but from the inner electrode to the outer, the current density $\vec j$ is proportional to $1/r$. The electric field is therefor also proportional to $1/r$. Now do your calculation for the potential again. I am not so sure that your measurement is wrong, anymore, but maybe your formula for what the potential should be is? :-)

Comment: That helps! I was able to fit it better and it looks really nice for a 1/r power law. I guess it is hard to get concrete help without showing the data to see what went wrong, but that definitely helped!